# Easiest way to navigate across tabs within terminals

Tags: gnome-terminal

Usually I have several gnome-terminals running, with several tabs each. Unfortunately, it is very difficult to navigate across them. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> only navigates across windows, not across terminals's tabs.

Is there anything that could display to me Titles of ALL tabs that I have opened across all gnome-terminals, and let me jump to it ?

Thanks,

ilyia

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl<.kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and PgDn</kbd> and should do the trick

-- peter

Comment: That only navigates within the tabs of the currently opened terminal. I wanna navigate across all tabs globally.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for tab 1 and so on, also works.

Comment: +1 Useful to know. This appears to work for other tabbed applications too.

Answer (score 4):

Useful gnome-terminal shortcuts:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> :- Open new tabs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> :- Close the current tabs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> :- Close all tabs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> :- copy to clipboard

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> :- paste from clipboard

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider using Terminator? I switched to it as my primary terminal. It lets you create new tabs (switching by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>) and split the window horizontally or vertically. https://edge.launchpad.net/terminator